# Last square of 8x8 grid not drawn, using two nested FOR loops

Tags: java

I'm having trouble understanding why my code isn't working. This should display a checkerboard grid that is 8x8, [but the last square doesn't get drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpPyO.png)! Any idea why?

I searched to see if this had been asked before, and didn't find anything. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
/*
* File:CheckerBoard.java
* ----------------------
*/

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

public class CheckerBoard extends GraphicsProgram {
int row, column, x, y;

    public void run() {

        // Checkerboard
        for (row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
                // x, y, x width, y width
                add(new GRect(x, y, 50, 50));
                x = column * 50;
                y = row * 50;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: The book I'm reading asks that I use two nested for loops (*"The Art and Science of Java"*, Chapter 4, Exercise 11, CS-106a)

Comment: Assign `x` and `y` _before_ using them in your rectangle.

Comment: Someday I hope to know what JAVA stands for.

Comment: @PaulBellora Java isn't an acronym. It just follows with the coffee theme.

Comment: @DaftPunk I guess that was too dry.

Comment: @PaulBellora coffee is a liquid, it can't become dry without changing states.

Comment: @DaftPunk Looks like you turned the tables on me. I can't tell if you're joking with that helmet on.

Comment: There is no need to add the major tag in the title.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set `x` and `y` before drawing the rectangle. Otherwise, the last rectangle is not going to display:

```
for (row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
        x = column * 50;
        y = row * 50;
        // x, y, x width, y width
        add(new GRect(x, y, 50, 50));
    }
}
```

Better yet, drop `x` and `y` altogether, and use calculations directly:

```
for (row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
    for (column = 0; column < 8; column++) {
        add(new GRect(column * 50, row * 50, 50, 50));
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, better to assign `y` outside the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Put the draw statement after setting x and y

Answer (score 0):

Since all of your variables are only used inside the `run()` method, they should be declared locally to that method rather than as member fields. Following this advice will help you find the error because the compiler will complain that `x` and `y` are uninitialized. As a general rule of thumb, you should declare and initialize variables as close as possible to their first use in code.